# How to inject MockMvc in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am following this tutorial about integration test in Spring Boot: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Well, but when I try to Inject MockMvc I always get:

> Error creating bean with name 'mockMvcBuilder' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder]:
>   Factory method 'mockMvcBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet

My test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    //Some code here
```

Well, I can see that it can't find the DispatcherServlet, but I'm not sure why is this happening... The test seams to be correct.

Does anyone knows what I am missing?

Edit:

This is the relevant part of my POM:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the actual Web dependencies in your project. Post your POM/`build.gradle`.

Comment: @chrylis Check my edit

Comment: I don't see `spring-boot-starter-web` anywhere.

Comment: I am using Jersey instead of Spring web. But, anyway, I will try to include the starter web

Comment: If you're not using Spring MVC, then MockMvc isn't available--it's not the stack you're actually running on.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the help! Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MockMvc is, as its name suggests, a mocked-up stack of Spring's Web MVC infrastructure (with mocked requests, responses, and so on). Since you're using Jersey, you won't be able to use MockMvc for testing. With Boot, you may want to use `@SpringBootTest` to launch the container on a random port and use `TestRestTemplate` to make (real, local) HTTP requests for testing.